# How to display user-defined / custom post in wordpress?

Tags: custom-post-types, loop

Just another basic question of wordpress development. 
I have a custom post created using the functions.php on theme folder that I am currently developing. 
I simply want to display all post from it.

```
function people() {
    register_post_type( 'people',
        array(
            'labels' => array(
                'name' => __( 'People' ),
                'singular_name' => __( 'People' ),
            ),
            'public' => true,
            'has_archive' => true,
            'supports' => array(
                'title',
                'editor',
                'thumbnail',
                'custom-fields'
            )
        ));
}
add_action( 'init', 'people' );
```

That is the function I have to put it on the wp-admin. 
and I tried to display it with this on `content-people.php` that is located in

`theme/my-theme/content-templates/content-people.php`

this is how I did it on my a section of my `index.php`:

```
<?php
if( have_posts( ) ): while( have_posts( ) ): the_post('people');

    get_template_part( 'content-templates/content', 'people');

endwhile;
endif;
?>
```

and this is what I have on `**content-people.php`

```
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 text-center">
    <div class="service-box">
        <i class="fa fa-4x fa-diamond text-primary sr-icons"></i>
        <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>

    </div>
</div>
```

But, it shows just the standard/default post from WordPress not the one that I have defined. 
I have tried to find it on WordPress codex guide, but still cannot find the exact solution for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for the response.
I think we have the same approach. 
here is what I have done and it works.

```
 <?php 
            $args =  array( 
                'post_type' => 'people',
                'orderby' => 'menu_order',
                'order' => 'ASC'
            );
             $custom_query = new WP_Query( $args );
                while ($custom_query->have_posts()) : $custom_query->the_post(); ?>
                    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 text-center">
                            <div class="service-box">
                                <i class="fa fa-4x fa-diamond text-primary sr-icons"></i>
                                    <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
                                        <p class="text-muted">
                                           <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
                                        </p>
                            </div>
                    </div>

                <?php endwhile; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

**index.php**

```
<?php 
$args = array(
       'post' => 'people',
       'post_status' => 'publish'
       )

 query_posts( $args ); ?>

<?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>


 <!-- the loop -->
 <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

   <?php get_template_part( 'content-templates/content', 'people' ); ?>

 <?php endwhile; ?>

<?php else : ?>
 <?php get_template_part( 'content-templates/content', 'none' ); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

**content-people.php**

```
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 text-center">
<div class="service-box">
   <i class="fa fa-4x fa-diamond text-primary sr-icons"></i>
       <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>

</div>
```

Hope this will helps you.

Answer (score 0):

You should go through the [**Template Hierarchy**](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/), it explains **how WordPress determines which template file(s) to use on individual pages**.

If you want to show the archive of all posts in your custom post type, you are going to need a new template file called **archive-{post_type}.php**.

In you scenario, you're going to create **archive-people.php** that would be located in **theme/my-theme/archive-people.php**

```
<?php
if( have_posts( ) ): while( have_posts( ) ): the_post('people');

    get_template_part( 'content-templates/content', 'people');

endwhile;
endif;
?>
```

This way wordpress loads this Template file when you visit yoursite at **`example.com/people`** and you don't have to write a custom query to handle the request.